# Split a string between 2 characters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I have the following string in Arcmap:

"Node 1_1234.23,Node 2_567.88,Node 3_45.25"

I want to return the numbers between the "_" and the "," into three columns

e.g  "1234.23" in column A
     "567.88" in column B
     "45.25 in column C

Pls assist with an expression I can use in field calculator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code and steps you will need to follow in Field Calculator:

```
def get_node(node_text,node_number):
   parts = node_text.split(',')
   node_val = float(parts[node_number][parts[node_number].find('_')+1:])
   return node_val
```

1. Make sure that Python is selected as the Parser option
2. Click on the Show Codeblock check box
3. Paste the above code into the Pre-Logic Script Code:
4. In the area below the code block enter the following formula (replacing !InputColumn! with the name of the column in your table that holds your data)

   - get_node(!InputColumn!,0)

   By changing the second parameter you can extract the other nodes from your input.

Edit:
I just realized that if you're not familiar with Python this may be fairly obtuse so here is a breakdown of what's happening in the code.

- The function takes two inputs, a string that is formatted as in your question and a number that indicates which node you want to extract
- The first line of the function breaks the input string into a list of sub-strings split by commas
- The next line parses the numerical value from node sub-string you specified.  It does this by searching the node string for the position of the underscore character and converting the remaining characters in the sub-string to a float value
- The last line passes the numerical node value back

Answer (score 3):

Field Calculator can only update one field at a time, so you could perform slight variations of a calculation for each field. Or, if you're willing to try a little Python you could use `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` to do it all at once. Could even just drop this into the Python window (modifying for your own table path and field names of course).

```
import arcpy
import re

# Update these 3 variables for your data
table = 'your_table'
in_field = 'your_starting_field'
update_fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, [in_field] + update_fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # this part will find numbers after a leading _
        nums = re.findall('(?<=_)[0-9.]+', row[0])
        cursor.updateRow([row[0]] + nums)
```